# Send Whatsapp message using a link

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

I came across a newsletter in which they have a WhatsApp link and when i click on it i am able send predefined message to predefined number.

SEND INQUIRY VIA WHATSAPP button is linked to below for example

https://whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXX&text=Hi%2C%20this%20is%20test%20message.

Can i use this link in my newsletter without any restriction as i have a database of 2000 subscribers...

or i have to use some sort of verified mechanism using API so that whatsapp is not abused.

This link seems to be vulnerable and can be used for spam or its fine to use it

Answer (score 0):

your URL is basically mal-formed.

The `whatsapp://` is a kind-of protocol for transmitting information, and what you can do is to add it to a webpage as a link, so the visitor, upon clicking on that link from their phone, can access directly to Whatsapp.

Remember the oldie-goldie `mailto://` which allow visitors to directly open the mail client they have on their computer, and pre-fill some email fields? This is the same.

Here is a really simple code-pen showing how can this be achieved.
Be sure to visit the codepen from your mobile:

https://codepen.io/diereysaa/pen/QWbjXGW

---

Replying to your specific question, there's no limitation on the use of this, since the executor will be each one of your subscribers, not your webserver. The only limitation will be your own phone, because if all of those 2,000 subscribers reply using the whatsapp link... you'll get 2,000 messages :D